# anydesk not launching on xfce4

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I installed anydesk latest repository using terminal the installation was smooth and didn't faced any error but it's not launching
**Note - I am using ubuntu xfce4 environment with tightvnc**

Comment: Please provide release details..